# I want to have a queue that push task to worker (celeryd) depend on interval time setting

Tags: celery, django-celery, celeryd

I 'm working of project that use celery, rabbitmq. I want to have right to control interval that queue push task to worker(celeryd).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for this documentation on [Periodic Tasks](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Essentially, you configure and run `celerybeat`, which fires off task executions at intervals.

**Word of warning**:
If it's undesirable to be running your task multiple times concurrently, I'd suggest you follow a [task locking recipe](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time). If your workers are busy or offline, you may end up with a backlog of periodic tasks.